# Why Firebase test-lab video is frozen at device details screen?

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab

It occurs with me often that the recorded video either doesn’t show some tests or any test and keeps freezing at “Device Details” page from start to end.

Can somebody help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on Firebase community on slack and got this reply from the support team which made sense in our use case:

[image]

This is the [link](https://firebase-community.slack.com/archives/C1MTSQ5QT/p1595978012351000?thread_ts=1594636151.193600&cid=C1MTSQ5QT) for the thread on Firebase community slack. Not sure though if it will redirect you